# How to reset an iOS device to clear away old application versions during testing?

Tags: ios

I'm developing an app and testing on an iPod with XCode. I just got rid of the default icon and splash screen and replaced them with custom files, but when I Build&Run, I still see the old one. How can I clear the old version of the app off of the device entirely? Surely somewhere there's a reset of some sort. I looked in the iPhone's general settings under Reset, but I didn't see an option that seemed pertinent.

Comment: This question pertains more to common practices when programming for iOS than anything else. I'm thinking about voting to migrate to [SO] since we only marginally deal with iOS here on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Organiser, you can restore/erase a device from there when it's connected to Xcode and set to developer mode.